# Bootstrap navbar can not open or will not close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i use bootstrap in my backbone project. I use only (For now) the 'classic' responsive navbar, that when you reduce the browser or enter with one mobile you see one botton and this expand the responsive menú, if you have big screen it see you tipical menu.

Like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html (You can see the text in the top menu, but if you reduce the browser screen you see the botton)

I have a problem in open/close moment in mobile/low-resolutions/etc. If i push to open the menu when it see the reduce version, sometimes it not open the menu, or sometimes it not close the menu. Sometimes close menu and reopened....

I don't search the concrete response, but, i need some guidance to find the CSS problem. ¿Where i see what happend when i push the navbar bottom in the reduce/responsive menu? I not have idea :(

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you for sure without looking at code but if you are not properly removing views from the DOM you could have multiple bindings to the click on the navbar.  So the view may not be showing but events are still being fired.  For example you could be showing the navbar and use it to navigate the page and somewhere along the line the navbar is recreated binding yet another event to it even though only one is showing. You need to make sure to unbind all events for your views.  A good article to solve this is:

[Backbone View Managment](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)

Just a thought but can't really know without looking at code.